# Xcode doesn't cout anything c++

Tags: c++, xcode

New to Xcode. I am aiming to run multiple short c++ programs in Xcode. Instead of creating two projects, I created two targets in the same project for convenience. However, it didn't run well. When I run the program, it didn't cout anything after showing "Building Successful". How I can fix it?

[image: This is the screenshot. It didn't show anything after being compiled]

Anyone can help?

Comment: Top right of your UI. three little toolbar buttons, the one with the bold section on the *bottom*. Click it.

Comment: It doesn't show any outputs. I know where to see the output window.

Comment: Interestingly, when the first target doesn't work, the second one doesn't work either. I believe they are different targets though